# Editable div not working on firefox

Tags: jquery

Hi i am using an dynamic div which is editable for input text. its working fine on IE but not on firefox. I need to show html content in div. can we make div editable for firefox also?

Comment: Post some of your code so we can work out where the problem might be

Answer (score 1):

Firefox requires the designMode to be set on an iFrame. The [specification](http://www.mozilla.org/editor/midas-spec.html) doesn't explicitly mention this but the following quote sort of implies it already

> For example, in JavaScript, if you
>   have an iframe with an id of 'edit',
>   you can get its contentDocument and
>   set designMode to "on" like this:

You will find alot of browser differences in how they handle designMode so be prepared and take it as a challenge or else you might lose a few hairs in the process.

Comment: can i use div with iframe can u explain with example?

Comment: Question has yet to unvague about there being an iframe being used. Or anything for that matter.

Comment: pradeep you need to render an iframe (or substitute the div with an iframe at runtime) to enable designMode. Designmode doesn't work on any other html element in FireFox.

Comment: Of course you can render `<div><iframe>...` if you must have a div container around it.